# Coding to avoid memory overcommit

Tags: c, memory, fork

I have a program in C which uses a lot of memory and runs for quite some time, and then at the end it needs to call `system()` to invoke a simple shell command (which uses little memory), but due to overcommit being disabled (and lack of swap), this call to `system()` may fail due to lack of available memory.

So far, it seems the only solution to avoid the memory issue is to add some asynchronous mechanism, e.g. invoking the `system()` call much earlier in the main process and then leaving the forked process waiting for the data to be sent later by the main process. This way, the forked process has a much smaller memory footprint.

Am I missing something? Is there a simpler way to invoke this external process without incurring on memory overcommit issues? I see some mentions to `vfork()`, but they seem to imply it is an outdated mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, `vfork()` wouldn't do anything for you that `fork()` does not do.  If you are on Linux, or on any other system that offers a `fork()` implemented using copy-on-write pages, then then ignore the existence (if any) of `vfork()` and consider only `fork()` for its purpose.

Neither gives you any advantage for your problem, however.  In fact, they take you in the wrong direction.  If the point is that you want the external command to use the resources that had already been reserved for the running program, then not only does doing anything in a forked process prevent that, but it also incurs a slight overhead of its own.

If the external command you want to execute is the *absolute last* thing your program does, however, then you can launch it directly via one of the `exec` family of library functions, such as `execlp()`, **without forking**.  These *replace* the process in which they run with the process being launched.

If that doesn't do it for you, then you could consider leaving the external process to be run separately, after the main program finishes.  Wrap the two commands together in a script.

Comment: To clarify: the main program processes a huge amount of information and writes it to a file. I then use an external tool which reads the file and produces a result. Note that this external tool does not use anything from the memory of the main process, and it consumes very little memory. Afterwards, the main program still has to read the result of the external tool and process it. Everything is serialized, but making a script would significantly complicate things.